# Navbar- dropdown toggle menu not working in bootstrap lib using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I just copied nav bar code from bootstrap lib, and dropdown menu is not working, My code:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Reports
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

New to react and bootstrap.

[Link to full file and project](https://github.com/yvr-satinder/mainMenu/blob/master/src/index.js)

the code is direct copy of Nav bar from lib. and still not working

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-wozniak-usbxgm?file=/src/index.js Please have a look at this how to use `React Bootstrap NavBar`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `React Bootstrap NavBar` this way:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import NavDropdown from "react-bootstrap/NavDropdown";

const CustomNav = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                Another action
              </NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                Separated link
              </NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<CustomNav />);
```

Live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-navbar-usbxgm

For more details about `React Bootstrap` components, have a look at these:

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

Comment: Can you help to fix it by just using bootstrap(the way am designing app in my code), The import you listed up top I have never build app that way.

Comment: Why don't you follow the official documentation? Navbar works with javascript as well as CSS.